# Physical path to application in global.asax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Guys, is it possible to get physical path to asp.net mvc 2 application inside Global.asax methods?

**UPD**: sorry, i forget to say, that I need to get that path in Ninject IoC container configuration.
This is a sketch of what i'm having now:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication 
{
    ...
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(IOCControllerFactory));
    }
}

public class IOCControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public IOCControllerFactory()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel(new NanocrmContainer());
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        var controller = kernel.TryGet(controllerType) as IController;

        if (controller == null)
            return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);

        var standartController = controller as Controller;

        return standartController;
    }

    class NanocrmContainer : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IFileService>().To<BusinessLogic.Services.FileService>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("temp", "Temp").WithConstructorArgument("docs", "Documents"); // Temp and Documents should be replaced with corresponding paths
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What difference does the update make?

Comment: @SLaks: nothing. i was inattentive, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for the [`HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx).

Comment: You're still looking for the [`HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx), and perhaps `Path.Combine`.

Comment: SLaks: that was my mistake - it was there, and i need glasses :-) thanks